# Rails Deface on input erb element, cannot override it correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree, deface

I am trying to override the qty input element in the products/_cart_form , to avoid a user modifying the qty
Should the Deface override be performed on the erb code or the html

I used the following override wo any success 
seems to be a mix of html selector and erb code ....  messy and tricky , obviously no example like this on the Deface github readme

```
 Deface::Override.new(
     :virtual_path => %q{spree/products/_cart_form},
     :name => %q{read_only_qty_cart_form},
     :set_attributes => %q{#cart-form form div.add-to-cart input},
     :attributes => {:readonly => 'readonly'}
 )
```

the spree/products/_cart_form.erb code is ( related to the input element)

```
    <div class="add-to-cart">
      <% if @product.on_sale? %>      
        <%= number_field_tag (@product.has_variants? ? :quantity : "variants[#{@product.master.id}]"),
          1, :class => 'title', :in => 1..@product.on_hand, :min => 1 , :readonly => true %>
        <%= button_tag :class => 'large primary', :id => 'add-to-cart-button', :type => :submit do %>
          <%= t(:add_to_cart) %>
        <% end %>
```

and it generates the following html :

```
 <div data-hook="cart_form" id="cart-form">
        <form method="post" action="/fr/orders/populate" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <div ...  name="authenticity_token"></div>
              <div...... data-hook="inside_product_cart_form" id="inside-product-cart-form">
                   <div class="columns five  alpha " data-hook="product_price">
                          <div id="product-price">....</div>
                          <div class="add-to-cart">
                                  <input type="number" value="1" name="variants[1001480408]" min="1" max="Infinity" id="variants_1001480408" class="title">
                                   <button type="submit" id="add-to-cart-button"..... >
                           </div>
                     </div>
               </div>
          </form> 
   </div>
```

Comment: I take a hard debug on how to deface dynamic view and finally I think it's impossible. the deface parse the view without introduce the variable bindings.so if the dynamic content depending on the variable,then the selector cant find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deface a generated element. Deface is run on the erb file (where the input element doesn't exist yet).

Try using a code deface like this:

```
Deface::Override.new(
     :virtual_path => "spree/products/_cart_form",
     :name => "read_only_qty_cart_form",
     :insert_bottom => "code[erb-loud]:contains('number_field_tag (@product.variants_and_option_values.any?')",
     :text => ", :readonly => 'readonly'"
)
```